# Console Logging Inner Html As A Single-Line String In Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string, dom, console.log

I'm trying to grab the innerHTML of a DOM element and log it into a console as a single line, but the console.log() function logs it with it's indentation as it appears on the page.

As simple example, on this article: http://www.nytimes.com/2015/11/27/world/europe/paris-attacks-have-many-in-france-eager-to-join-the-fight.html?_r=0
I can retrieve the innerHTML of the first paragraph:

```
document.getElementById('story-continues-1').innerHTML
```

Running this in the chrome console returns the text as one long, single-line string, which is what I want. Except when I console.log() that same code:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('story-continues-1').innerHTML)
```

it gets returned in pretty, paragraph form, not as one long line. 
Help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no help here - it's how Chrome's console works. It simply won't allow horizontal scrolling and in your string `"PARIS — The attacks by militants tied to the Islamic State less than two weeks ago in Paris have awakened a patriotic fervor in <a href="http://topics.nytimes.com/top/news/international/countriesandterritories/france/index.html?inline=nyt-geo" title="More news and information about France." class="meta-loc">France</a> not seen in decades."` it simply breaks lines on spaces.

You can't change the way their console works, unless you build your own browser.

If you need just the text, you can do:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('story-continues-1').textContent)
```

Comment: My example wasn't as illustrative as I thought, my apologies.
Check this page:
http://www.super-resume.com/ResumeBuilder.jtp?query=computer+support+analyst
And again, compare this:

     $('[data-category=text][class=block]').eq(0).text()

With the same thing console logged. 

In the console logged version, it doesn't just give shift the string down at the end of each line; it actually preserves the same p-graph structure as it appears in the html element itself (if you inspect it). 
"Professional computer
consultant,".... etc. 

I want it to be logged as a string without the line breaks.

Comment: Oh, I understand, the first case returns a pure string while the second returns a formatted output without horizontal scrolling. But I don't think there's a way to change/trick it. This is the problem: `console.log('any string');`... `JSON.stringify` helps up to a point, but still not a one-liner.

Comment: What's odd is I don't understand where the where the console gets this formatting information. I mean, a string is a string, right? Just a sequence of characters? Where is this data about how to properly format it being stored/retrieved?

Comment: Yes, but they seem to change the output based on the type (I always loved how they style objects). It's a part of the JS runtime, you could probably dig something interesting up by looking the source code of Chromium.

Answer (score -1):

Json.stringify (thanks Shomz) is what I was looking for. It reveals that the string contained hidden /n characters which were creating the new lines. Once those are removed, the strings logs in a single line as desired.